# Decomposing the mutual information between conditionally independent variables and the conditioning variable?

Tags: information-theory

Assume X and Y are conditionally independent given Z:
$P(X,Y|Z)=P(X|Z)P(Y|Z)$.

We are interested in the mutual information between P(X,Y) and P(Z): $I(X,Y;Z)$. Can we decompose this mutual information into two components reflecting the contribution of $X$ and $Y$ separately?

Concretely, can there be a functional $f$ and a binary function $g$ such that
$I(X,Y;Z)=g(f(P(X,Z)),f(P(Y,Z)))$?

What I have tried:

$I(X,Y;Z)=H(X,Y)-H(X,Y|Z)=H(X,Y)-H(X|Z)-H(Y|Z)$

The second equality is due to the additivity of entropies of independent variables (it holds for each $z$). I am left with $H(X,Y)$ which doesn't easily decompose ($X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily independent when not conditioned on Z).

Note: this question is superficially very similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521361/decomposition-of-mutual-information-for-conditionally-independent-variables), but it is not equivalent to it.

Comment: Can you be more concrete? My interpretation is that you're asking if there is some functional $f$ such that for any $P_{XYZ}$ such that $X$ and $Y$ are indepenent given $Z$, $I(X,Y;Z) = f(P_{XZ}) + f(P_{YZ})$ (the $f$ would have to be the same since $I(X,Y;Z) = I(Y,X;Z)$). Is this a fair way to state your question?

Comment: If so, my immediate instinct is that this is not possible in general. Here's a proposed proof (I haven't checked this properly): Suppose such an $f$ exists. Take $P_{Y|Z} = P_{X|Z} = \delta_{a}$ (i.e. the trivial channel which map all inputs to one fixed output) to argue that for any $P_Z, a$ $f(P_Z \circ \delta_a)$ has to be $0$. Then making only one of the channels trivial this says that $f(P_{XZ}) = I(X;Z).$  But this cannot be the case since $I(X,Y;Z) = I(X;Z) + I(Y;Z)$  is not true in general.

Comment: Operationally this shouldn't hold because the information $X$ and $Y$ individually provide about $Z$ can overlap, and to find 'how much' this overlap is you have to consider the properties of $X$ and $Y$ together, ergo the joint law $P_{XY}$ must enter the picture at some point.

Comment: Thank you for the formalizing my question, I edited the question accordingly. I agree with your interpretation, except that the summation operation isn't mandatory, I'd be happy with any binary function applied to the two functionals.

Comment: I do not follow the last step of your proof. I see how $f(P_{XZ})$ must equal $I(X;Z)$ when $P_{Y|Z}$ is the trivial channel but since this a special case, why does it mean that $f(P_{XZ})=I(X;Z)$ in general?

Comment: $P_{XZ}$ doesn't depend on $P_{Y|Z},$ right? So if we can compute $f(P_{XZ})$ for one choice of $P_{Y|Z}$, then we've effectively computed for every $P_{Y|Z}$, since $f(P_{XZ})$ doesn't involve $P_{Y|Z}$ at all. That said I don't know if this argument extends to the more general setting you pose.

Comment: Due to the representation you have, the question is equivalent to asking if you can write the joint entropy of X and Y as a functional of the above form. But for this I don't see why the conditional independence given Z would help at all. Maybe there's a way to cook up a proof of impossibility via this?

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your time!